# Why won't my legs rotate at the top instead of the centre

Tags: opengl, c++, glut

As the title suggests, I'm battling with getting the legs of my model here to rotate properly. They rotate in the middle instead of at the top where the knee joint would be. So far I've tried translating them to 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 before calling the glrotate function on my body parts but all that does is move the lower leg further away from the upper leg and keep the issue going. I can't figure this out.

[Visual of Issue](https://gyazo.com/51f62ceb2a0c5d32f31db44897ec4481)

```
#include <glut.h>

float angle[4];
float LightAngle;
GLuint texture;

bool LowerFrontLegDown = true;
bool LowerBackLegDown = true;


GLfloat corners[8][3] = { {-0.5,0.5,-0.5},{0.5,0.5,-0.5},
                        {0.5,-0.5,-0.5},{-0.5,-0.5,-0.5},
                        {-0.5,0.5,0.5},{0.5,0.5,0.5},
                        {0.5,-0.5,0.5},{-0.5,-0.5,0.5} };

//Two Dimensional Array for the corners of the cube

GLfloat normals[][3] = { {0.0,0.0,1.0},
                                      {1.0,0.0,0.0},
                                      {0.0,-1.0,0.0},
                                      {0.0,1.0,0.0},
                                      {0.0,0.0,-1.0},
                                      {-1.0,0.0,0.0} };

//Normal maps for the cube to apply lighting to it when the program runs

typedef struct materialStruct {
    GLfloat ambient[4];
    GLfloat diffuse[4];
    GLfloat specular[4];
    GLfloat shininess;
};

materialStruct redPlasticMaterial = {
       { 0.30, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00 },
       { 0.60, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00 },
       { 0.80, 0.60, 0.60, 1.00 },
       32.00 };

materialStruct* currentMaterial;



void setMaterial(materialStruct* materials) {
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, materials->ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, materials->diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, materials->specular);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, materials->shininess);
}

//Defines a material that is then applied to the model

void drawFace(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3fv(corners[a]);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3fv(corners[b]);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3fv(corners[c]);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3fv(corners[d]);
    glEnd();
} 

//Turns the corners from the two dimensional array into corner pieces for the model, allowing faces to be drawn and in turn, allowing for the model giraffe to be drawn

void ArrayCube() {
    glNormal3fv(normals[0]);
    drawFace(0, 3, 2, 1);
    glNormal3fv(normals[1]);
    drawFace(3, 0, 4, 7);
    glNormal3fv(normals[2]);
    drawFace(2, 3, 7, 6);
    glNormal3fv(normals[3]);
    drawFace(1, 2, 6, 5);
    glNormal3fv(normals[4]);
    drawFace(4, 5, 6, 7);
    glNormal3fv(normals[5]);
    drawFace(5, 4, 0, 1);
}
//Draws the faces of the model and creates a cube we can call later for the individual parts of the model.

void rotate() {
    angle[0] += 1.0;
    if (angle[0] > 360) angle[0] -= 360;

    if (LowerFrontLegDown) angle[1] -= 0.2;
    else angle[1] += 0.2;

    if (angle[1] < 315) LowerFrontLegDown = false;
    if (angle[1] > 360) LowerFrontLegDown = true;

    angle[0] += 1.0;
    if (angle[0] > 360) angle[0] -= 360;

    if (LowerBackLegDown) angle[1] -= 0.2;
    else angle[1] += 0.2;

    if (angle[1] < 315) LowerBackLegDown = false;
    if (angle[1] > 360) LowerBackLegDown = true;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void MainBody()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(1.25, 0.25, 0.5);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void LowerNeck()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5, 0.25, 0);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void UpperNeck()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5, 0.75, 0);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void Head()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(90, 0.0, 0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(1, -0.6, 0);
    glScalef(0.1, 0.4, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void RightHorn()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(0, 0.0, 0.0,1);
    glTranslatef(0.5, 1.15, 0.035);
    glScalef(0.05, 0.15, 0.05);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void LeftHorn()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
    glTranslatef(0.5, 1.15, -0.035);
    glScalef(0.05, 0.15, 0.05);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void FrontUpperRightLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.35, 0.15);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void FrontLowerRightLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.85, 0.15);
    glRotatef(angle[1], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void FrontUpperLeftLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.35, -0.15);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void FrontLowerLeftLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.85, -0.15);
    glRotatef(angle[1], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();

    glPopMatrix();
}

void BackUpperRightLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.5, -0.35, -0.15);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void BackLowerRightLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.5, -0.85, -0.15);
    glRotatef(angle[1], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void BackUpperLeftLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.5, -0.35, 0.15);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void BackLowerLeftLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.5, -0.85, 0.15);
    glRotatef(angle[1], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void Tail()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.65, -0.25, 0);
    glScalef(0.05, 0.75, 0.05);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}

//Each of the below functions draws an individual part of the whole model and places those parts where they need to go once the program runs

void DrawGiraffe()
{
    MainBody();
    LowerNeck();
    UpperNeck();
    Head();
    RightHorn();
    LeftHorn();
    FrontUpperRightLeg();
    FrontLowerRightLeg(); 
    FrontUpperLeftLeg();
    FrontLowerLeftLeg();
    BackUpperRightLeg();
    BackLowerRightLeg();
    BackUpperLeftLeg();
    BackLowerLeftLeg();
    Tail();

}

//Calls the above functions to render the final model

//The rotate function allows the camera to rotate around the model

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    DrawGiraffe();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    GLubyte image[64][64][3];
    int i, j, r, c;
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            c = ((((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)) == 0)) * 255;
            image[i][j][0] = (GLubyte)c;
            image[i][j][1] = (GLubyte)c;
            image[i][j][2] = (GLubyte)c;
        }
    }
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    currentMaterial = &redPlasticMaterial;
    setMaterial(currentMaterial);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 2.5);
    GLfloat light_pos[] = {2.0,2.0,2.0, 1.0};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_pos);     
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    angle[0] = 0;
    angle[1] = 360;
    angle[2] = 315;
    angle[3] = 0;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Giraffe");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(rotate);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a lot of code here not directly related to the knee issue (materials, neck, and other body parts...) - you'll likely get answers faster if you trim your code down to a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Say, just a single cube rotating on its edge.

Comment: I can get a single cube rotating perfectly fine, my issue is the lower leg not rotating at it's edge so it acts like a knee joint, I know it's a lot of code but this is for a Uni assignment and I don't have much time left to finish it, I'd prefer not to set up another two joints to replicate the isse.

Answer (score 2):

`glRotatef` always rotates around the origin.

When rotating around an arbitrary point `p` you should first translate by `-p`, do the rotation, and then translate by `p`.

Also when you have a hierarchical structure you will want to nest the matrix manipulation:

```
void FrontUpperRightLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.35, 0.15);
    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    FrontLowerRightLeg(); //draw the lower leg relative to the upper leg before popping the matrix
    glPopMatrix();
}

void FrontLowerRightLeg()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    //adjust parameters to account for the coordinate being relative to the upper leg
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.85, 0.15); 

    glTranslatef(...); 
    glRotatef(angle[1], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(...); //translate by the negation

    glScalef(0.15, 0.5, 0.15);
    ArrayCube();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

that way when you rotate the upper leg the lower leg will move along with it with no extra code.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the lower leg rotating at the knee joint correctly, I'm not trying to get both leg parts rotating, I'm not sure I fully follow though, nest the matrix? and translate by negation? Sorry I'm incredibly new to Open GL and the resources I have from my tutor are almost no help at this point. They got me this far but I'm stuck xD

Comment: translating by `p =(px, py, pz)` will move a point `p1 (x, y, z)` to point `(x+px, y+py, z+pz)` moving a point by negative p will move it to `(x-px, y-py, z-pz)` and move that point to the origin ready to be rotated on. Then you move it back.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still not entirely sure what i'm reading, I've tried to research and google it but I genuinely don't you mean, sorry, I understand as far as I need to move the top of the leg to the origin, which as I understand is always 0, 0, 0, so I tried doing: glTranslatef(0, 0, 0), before the rotate, didn't do anything as far as I can tell.